# Remove categories from product page (WooCommerce)

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

On my website, the "shop" page which is supposed to only display products is displaying all of the categories first, followed by the products.

I would like to remove the categories from the product listing. You can see an example of the problem at http://thehonestpet.com/shop/

Categories showing up as products on shop page:

[image: Categories]

Please advise?

I'm not finding any settings within WordPress to fix this. Perhaps a CSS fix?

The following works, but only hides the categories from the "Shop" page but not the product category page...thoughts?

```html
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );
function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
  $new_terms = array();

  // if a product category and on the shop page
  if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
      if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'bedding', 'feeders-bowls', 'accessories', 'food', 'treats' ) ) ) {
        $new_terms[] = $term;
      }

    }

    $terms = $new_terms;
  }

  return $terms;
}
```

Comment: This is not about programming. WoCommerce settings > Products > Display… Try changing settings.

Comment: I did check there. It is saying "Products" but yet displaying the categories as well

Comment: It can come also from your category settings in Products > category (for each category)… Or it can be related to the theme behaviors (customizations).

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in function.php

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

Answer (score 2):

The other 2 answers are really close, just needed to add an extra bit on the end:

```html
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce product categories are displayed at the bottom of a product page just under the add to cart button.

You can remove these from the layout by removing the **woocommerce_template_single_meta** action from the product summary, in your themes functions.php.

like this :

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

This will remove the categories aka product meta from the layout.

Comment: The categories in this case are listed as if they are products, and they show before the products on the shop page. You can see what I mean on the page I shared. This is on the shop page, NOT the product page.

Comment: See Link For Your Question [link](https://www.ultimatewoo.com/how-to-remove-product-categories-from-woocommerce-shop-page/) Hope you found what you looking

Comment: Didn't really work. Found a code snippet (posted in my original question) that somewhat helped, but still not accomplishing what I need.